# C# Outlook send one email to multiple recipients

Tags: c#, outlook

i have been trying to figure out how to send outlook email via C# to multiple recipients. For now i can do a loop among the recipients, but there is going to a lot of sent emails in my sent box.

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            oMsg.HTMLBody ="test";
            oMsg.Subject = "test" ;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;        
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("xxx@xxx.com");
            oRecip.Resolve();
            oMsg.Send();
            oRecip = null;
            oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;
```

If i add multiple address to it like:
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("xxx@xxx.com,yyy@yyy.com,zzz@zzz.com") 
This will not work somehow. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @Yun...what do you 'will not work somehow'.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: If possible have your email admins create a single group that you email to.  That way you won't have to recompile whenever the business adds or removes a recipient.

Comment: Outlook does not recognize one or more names.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to separate each user by a semicolon. For example look at my code below.

```
Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
 Outlook.Application objApp = new Outlook.Application();               
 mail=(Outlook.MailItem)objApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

  mail.Subject ="HI";
  mail.To = "personone@yahoo.com; Persontwo@yahoo.com";
  mail.Attachments.Add("C:\SOME_FOLDER\SomeFile");
  mail.Body="xxxxxx";
  mail.Send();
```

Answer (score 4):

("xxx@example.com,yyy@example.org,zzz@meta.example.com") isn't the divider a semi-colon as in 
("xxx@example.com; yyy@example.org; zzz@meta.example.com") ??

If I go into my Outlook and send to multiple people it's a semi-colon displayed in the to: field.

Comment: fair enough it was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call "oRecips.Add" for each recipient? After all it's ADDING to the RECIPIENTS...?

EDIT: Just verified:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

 oMsg.HTMLBody = "test";
 oMsg.Subject = "test";
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;

 foreach (var recipient in new string[] { "a@b.c", "c@d.e" })
 {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(recipient);
      oRecip.Resolve();
 }
 oRecips = null;

 oMsg.Send();
 oMsg = null;
 oApp = null;
```

will create ONE sent item with any number of recipients, just like I thought.

Comment: If i send email to 50 people, i don;t want to see 50 email in sent box.

Comment: It shouldn't - unless you also create 50 message objects rather than just calling add on the same message 50 times. That's how it worked with older Outlook versions, I'll try to verify with 2010 once I'm at an equipped computer.

Comment: If your sending 50 emails programatically you might want to send them BCC so each recipient can't see your whole mailing list. This might also break GDPR because you're exposing private information.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working fine for sending multiple recipients

```
            private static void SendMail(string body){
            try   { string tomail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToMailString"];
            string[] allToAddresses = tomail.Split(";,".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem tempItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem email = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)(oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
            email.Subject = "Status Report";
            email.Body = body;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipients)email.Recipients;
            int mailcount1 = 1;
            for (; mailcount1 < allToAddresses.Length; mailcount1++)
            {
                if (allToAddresses[mailcount1].Trim() != "")
                {
                    //email.Recipients.Add(allToAddresses[mailcount1]);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(allToAddresses[mailcount1]);
                    oRecip.Resolve();
                }
            }

            oRecips = null;
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)email).Send(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Mail Sent");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code if you want to send multiple persons add them in cc or bcc or to as your wish

```
public void SendAutomatedEmail(string htmlString, string subject, string from, string fromPwd, string recipient)
    {
        try
        {
            string mailServer = "xxxxExchangesver.com";
            string[] allToAddresses = recipient.Split(";,".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, allToAddresses[0]);
            int mailcount1 = 1;
            for (; mailcount1 < allToAddresses.Length; mailcount1++)
            {
                if (allToAddresses[mailcount1].Trim() != "")
                    message.To.Add(allToAddresses[mailcount1]);
            }
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = htmlString;
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.CC.Add(from);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);

            var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential(from, fromPwd);
            client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(message);
            client.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            status(e.Message, Color.Red);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While I would also vote for a solution that doesn't involve any office components, the original question was how to do it with Outlook. This solution uses the SMTP client which isn't aware of any Mail Profile that Outlook might have set up amongst other things that might be important to the OP...